# Swift: how to set AnyObject to nil or equivalent

Tags: swift

I have a very generic function which needs to return `AnyObject`:

```
func backgroundFunction(dm : DataManager) -> AnyObject {
    ...
}
```

however there are some cases where I would like to return an **empty/null value**

I thought about these two values:

- `nil`

but it doesn't seem to be allowed: *Type 'AnyObject' does not conform to protocol 'NilLiteralConvertible'*

- `0`

but when I test if that AnyObject value is 0 with `value != 0` I get this error: *Binary operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'AnyObject' and 'nil'*

Is there any solution?

Comment: Make it return an optional AnyObject: AnyObject?. Only optionals can be set to and checked for nil.

Comment: @Arbitur, I just tried using an optional AnyObject, and it actually works! thanks, I thought you couldn't have optionals as returning values in a function

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Only an optional value can be set to nil or checked for nil. So you have to make your return type an optional.

```
func backgroundFunction(dm : DataManager) -> AnyObject? {
    ...
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution by returning an optional AnyObject:

```
func backgroundFunction(dm : DataManager) -> AnyObject? {

     if IHaveAValueToReturn {
         return TheValueToReturn
     }

     return nil
     // in case of optional AnyObject, you are allowed to return nil

}
```

Comment: Actually, instead of your comment you should write **return nil**

Comment: @appzYourLife, you are actually right, in case of optional AnyObject you are allowed to return nil, I am going to edit it

Comment: Ok good, just to make clear that a return statement is required in every branch of your function.

Comment: it was actually working even without a return statement

Comment: Hmm...  the return statement is mandatory for every branch. I don't think it can work otherwise.

Comment: If you have an if else and a return in both you dont need the return at the end,

Comment: @Arbitur, yes sure, go ahead I will select it as the answer

Comment: @Arbitur: it is exactly what I said: you need a return statement for every branch the execution does follow. Of course if you don't put a **return** in the **then** and in the **else** both branches become the same at the end of the function. In this case my statement is still true because **every branch has a return statement**. But the code in the answer was different. There was only a **return** in the **then** and this is illegal.